# Can I open a file at an arbitrary line and column via the command line?

Tags: command-line

I'm working on [Open::This](https://metacpan.org/pod/Open::This), which provides a command line utility that acts as a wrapper around `vim`, `emacs` and `nano`.  The utility is called `ot`.  It does things like translating `ot lib/Foo/Bar.pm:99` into `vim +99 lib/Foo/Bar.pm`.

What I'd like to be able to do is translate `ot lib/Foo/Bar.pm:99:50` into a `vim` command which will open `lib/Foo/Bar.pm` at line 99 and column 50.  Is this possible to do *without* using a `vim` plugin?

To sum up, I know the command line syntax to open a file at an arbitrary line.  Is it possible to do this *and* move the cursor to an arbitrary column at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have vim execute arbitrary commands (i.e., not just a line number) after loading the first file on the command line using `+'{cmd}'` or `-c '{cmd}'`.  This is documented in vim's man page.  For example, to load file `Foo/Bar.pm` then go to line 99, column 50, you can use:

```
vim +'call cursor(99,50)' Foo/Bar.pm
```

Note that this uses byte position for the column number, starting from one.  If your file has multi-byte characters and you wish to use vim's understanding of column numbers instead, you can instead do:

```
vim +'normal! 99G50|' Foo/Bar.pm
```

This uses the normal commands `G` for go-to line and `|` meaning go to screen column (starting at one).

Which to use depends on how your tool emits column numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
vim -c "call cursor(19, 11)" .bashrc
```

This opens `.bashrc` and puts the cursor on line 19, column 11.

Note that `<TAB>` is one character!